# Crazy idea of new tag in html

Tags: javascript

I want to create a tag named `<triangle>`. And I want to add new css attributes, like `width-a`, `width-b`, and `width-c`. (Widths of the three sides of the triangle).

I have already the calculations in JavaScript, and I know how to create tags and append them, and I know how to seek all `<triangle>` tags and change their styles.

But if the one who will use my library for `<triangle>` tags append a `<triangle>` tag in javascript, this will not be formated as it must. Then I thought of an interval, but there would be like a blink before the triangle appears.

Is there a way to modify the `appendChild` (or the `createElement`) function so that I modify the tag that will be appended before it's appended?

(Of course, any other way to make that someone could just write:

```
var a=document.createElement("triangle");
a.style.borderA="100px";
a.style.borderB="100px";
a.style.borderC="100px";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

will be accepted)

---

<sub>No jQuery please</sub>

Comment: Maybe you can make use of data values in HTML. **data-width-a=100px; data-width-b=100px; data-width-c=200px;**. Data attributes are easy to manipulate and can standardize other people use.

Comment: @MurifoX Using data values won't change anything. Even if I use data values, and the one who uses my library append the tag in javascript, the render will not be a triangle (except if I seek all triangle tags in a setInterval, but this will surely do a blink before the triangle appears)

Comment: Not a real answer for you but it's not a good idea to add a new html tag named <whatever>, you may use <namespace:whatever> instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `createElement` function, injecting a place to listen for the creation process:

```
(function () {
    // cache the old createElement function
    var createElement = document.createElement;

    // override the createElement function
    document.createElement = function ( tag ) {
        // create a normal element
        var el = createElement.call(document, tag);

        // execute all pseudo-event handlers
        for (var i = 0, il = document.createElement.hooks.length; i < il; ++i) {
            document.createElement.hooks[i].call(el, el);
        }

        // still return the element
        return el;
    };

    // create a place to register "events"
    document.createElement.hooks = [];
})();
```

Once overridden, you are free to hook into the creation process. Now any new triangles you create will automatically have their style attributes set:

```
// register a new "event" hook
document.createElement.hooks.push(function () {
    if (this.tagName === 'TRIANGLE') {
        this.style.borderA = "100px";
        this.style.borderB = "100px";
        this.style.borderC = "100px";
    }
});

var el = document.createElement('triangle');
document.body.appendChild(el);
```